# Sqlalchemy use json_set to update specific JSON field

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy, mysql-json

I intend to use `func` function to update a specific JSON field in Sqlalchemy, but I get some problem, here is my code to update field:

```
self.db.query(TestModel).filter(TestModel.test_id == self._test_id).update(
    {field_name: func.json_set(
        field_name,
        "$." + key,
        formatted_val)}
    , synchronize_session='fetch'
)
self.db.commit()
```

I ran the code above and got the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) malformed JSON
```

So, I go to check the log, found Sqlalchemy form an SQL clause like that:

```
UPDATE test_model SET field_name=json_set('field_name', '$.keyname', 'value') WHERE test_model.test_id = 1;
```

the problem is Sqlalchemy should not use `'field_name'` to specific the field it should use `field_name` to specific the field, and I try to run corrected sql clause below in sql client:

```
UPDATE test_model SET field_name=json_set(field_name, '$.keyname', 'value') WHERE test_model.test_id = 1;
```

and it work find

I just want to know how to make the Sqlalchemy form the correct field from `'field_name'` to `field_name`?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass first parameter with a name of model to function `func.json_set`:

```
self.db.query(TestModel).filter(TestModel.test_id == self._test_id).update(
    {field_name: func.json_set(
        TestModel.field_name,
        "$." + key,
        formatted_val)}, 
     synchronize_session='fetch'
)
self.db.commit()
```